# Read integers from a file and perform addition and output result to the same file using java

Tags: java, file, io

```
//hello.txt

1
2
3
4
5
```

I have the above file wherin I read the file as show below and perform a summation on it. I need to store result in the same file without replacing the contents. how do I do this?

```
package filereadwrite;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadFile
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws IOException
    {
        Scanner textfile = new Scanner(new File("D:/hello.txt"));

        filereader(textfile);
    }   


    static void filereader(Scanner textfile) {
        int sum = 0;          
        while(textfile.hasNextInt()) {
            int nextInt = textfile.nextInt();
            System.out.println(nextInt);
            sum += nextInt;

        }
        System.out.println("Sum= "+sum);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FileWriter` to write the sum back to file and initial it as below :

```
FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter("D:/hello.txt", true);
filewriter.write(String.valueOf(sum));
filewriter.flush();
filewriter.close();
```

As per java doc

Constructs a `FileWriter` object given a `File` object. If the second argument is `true`, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.

Comment: What issue you facing dear !!

Comment: static void filereader(Scanner textfile) throws IOException {
     int sum = 0;          
     while(textfile.hasNextInt()) {
         int nextInt = textfile.nextInt();
         System.out.println(nextInt);
         sum += nextInt;
        
         FileWriter filewriter= new FileWriter("D:/hello.txt", true);
        
    filewriter.write(sum);
   }
   
     System.out.println("Sum="+sum);
    }

Comment: I have done the above sir. But nothin is written to the file.

Comment: Updated the answer, you dont close the writer .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49594/discussion-between-youngistan-and-vidya)

Comment: I did sir. Now some text is appended to the file. Some unknown text.

Comment: what do you mean by unknown text ?